# Sublime text TODO and others highlighting

Tags: sublimetext, sublimelinter

I'm looking for a way to highlight TODOs and TODO-like in Sublime text.

I tried Linter and SublimeLinter-annotations but I cannot find a way or a clear documentation to better highlight the TODO line.

I put this in the `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings`:

```
// SublimeLinter Settings - User
{
    // "debug": true,
    
    "linters": {
        "annotations": {
            "infos": ["TODO"],
            "warnings": ["WARNING"],
            "errors": ["ERROR"],
            "mark_message": true,
        },
    }
}
```

with this result:

[image: linter]

More on large files, for me, this highlight isn't clearly visible.

How to?

- set the foreground and background colors of the whole comment line
- highlight also multi-line comments like `/* TODO ... \n ... */`

Other than TODOs, I need to highlight also `// TEST` and `// INFO` comments with different colors.

I already tried `SublimeTODO` but it highlights also nested comments.

Comment: Are there particular types of files you;d like to have this in, or do you want it to work in all types of files no matter what?

Comment: @OdatNurd in all types of files

Comment: Note that you're not really looking for a "TODO" highlighter, you're looking for a text highlighter. And then you tell it that "TODO: ..." is something it should highlight.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans correct, the main purpose is for TODOs, but it's useful to use the same approach to highlight others too

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `ToDoColor.sublime-syntax` in your Sublime User directory (In my case Win10: `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages\User`)
2. Paste there something like that (I created this one for my todo list):

   ```
   %YAML 1.2

   ---
   name: ToDoColor
   file_extensions: [ todo ] # you can add your extension/s here
   scope: source.MyScopeName

   contexts:
     main:
       - match: '\b(TODO|todo)\b'
         scope: entity.name.class
       - match: '\b(DONE|done)\b'
         scope: string
       - match: '\b(PENDING|pending)\b'
         scope: entity.name.function
       - match: '\b(DROP|drop)\b'
         scope: entity.name.tag
       - match: '#.*'
         scope: comment.line
   ```
3. Next create file with provided above extension (.todo in my case)
4. View - Syntax - ToDoColor
5. You should see something like this for this text:

   ```
   TODO or todo
   DONE or done
   PENDING or pending
   DROP or drop
   # Commented line
   ```

[image]

FYI: Of course you can add your words/regexes and I used [build-in colors](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/scope_naming.html) here

So for your specific case you can insert this part before comment sign:

```
- match: '(#.*?\b)(TODO|todo)(.*)'
  captures:
      1: comment.line
      2: entity.name.class.todo
      3: comment.line
```

[image]

Comment: While this is a good explanation of creating custom syntax, it hardly answers the question: there aim is to extend *all* syntaxes so that TODO triggers highlighting. So a Python file should still be highlighted as Python, plus `# TODO: ...` marked with color. Same for md, c, js or whatever, without having to modify files for every language

Comment: This plugin highlight todo’s: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Colored%20Comments

Answer (score -1):

You can try with new custom `.tmTheme` color scheme file:

- Example for TODO inside `CustomColorScheme.tmTheme`:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>TODO</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>annotation.todo</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#FF0000</string>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>#FFFF00</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Then add the custom scheme path to the default settings file or user-specific settings file located at `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings`

```json
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/CustomColorScheme/CustomColorScheme.tmTheme"
}
```

[Reference Link](https://chenhuijing.com/blog/creating-a-custom-sublime-text-colour-scheme/)

Comment: Does it'll let me highlight all the line, not only the TODO string? Please add a working completed example